# Android how to get time difference between two time zones in android?

Tags: java, android, timezone

I need to get time difference between two dates in different time zones. Currently I am doing this:

```
Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String diff=((c2.getTimeInMillis()-c1.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60*60))+" hours";
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(diff).create().show();
```

I get `0` hours. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For new readers to this old question I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone` . Both classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). May also use other classes from the same API.

Comment: Two things are wrong: (1) The `TimeZone` class used when you asked didn’t understand `EDT` and very confusingly tacitly gave you GMT, thus pretending all was well. So your two times zones were the same. (2) Your expectations to the `Calendar` class (also cumbersome and now fortunately long outdated) were wrong. The time-in-millis it returned were independent of time zone. Related: [Java: getTimeZone without returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373442/java-gettimezone-without-returning-a-default-value).

Answer (score 17):

`getTimeInMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds *since the epoch in UTC*. In other words, the time zone is irrelevant to it.

I suspect you actually want:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
int edtOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(srcZoneId).getOffset(currentTime);
int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(targetZoneId).getOffset(currentTime);
int hourDifference = (gmtOffset - edtOffset) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
String diff = hourDifference + " hours";
```

... where `srcZoneId` and `targetZoneId` are *valid* time zone IDs. Note that "EDT" is not a time zone ID; it's sort of "half a time zone" at best. I would *strongly* recommend avoiding the 3-letter abbreviations, which don't actually identify time zones. For example, using "America/New_York" and "Europe/London" for the above would be fine.

And of course, while the above was a reasonable approach back in 2011, if you're using Java 8 or above it's *definitely* worth using classes in java.time rather `java.util.Calendar`, `java.util.TimeZone` etc.

Comment: And what in case of Daylight Saving? will that handle it?

Comment: @Gugan: I don't know what will happen if you use an abbreviation for the time zone name - but if you give it a full time zone ID such as `Europe/London`, that will indeed handle daylight saving.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The question and the [answer written at that time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760179/10819573) use the `java.util` date-time API which was the right thing to do in 2011. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`

**Do not use three-letter timezone ID**: Before doing it using the modern date-time API, let's see the following important note from the Java 7 `Timezone` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

**The desired solution:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        long offest1InSec = ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getOffset(now).getTotalSeconds();
        long offest2InSec = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC").getRules().getOffset(now).getTotalSeconds();
        long hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(offest2InSec - offest1InSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(hours);
    }
}
```

**Output now**<sup>*</sup>:

```
5
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eIDgHD)

### It gets even simpler if the desired difference is from GMT/UTC

The above solution is a general solution for any two time zones. However, if the desired difference is from GMT/UTC, it gets even simpler. In this case, you don't need to calculate the difference because the offset of a time zone is always given w.r.t. UTC whose offset is `00:00` hours.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long hours = Math.abs(TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(
                ZoneId.of("America/New_York").getRules().getOffset(Instant.now()).getTotalSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        System.out.println(hours);
        
        // Alternatively,
        hours = Math.abs(TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(
                ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).getOffset().getTotalSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        System.out.println(hours);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
5
5
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* US Eastern Time (e.g. *America/New_York*) observes [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). During the DST period, its offset from UTC is 4 hours and during the non-DST period (e.g. now, 28-Jan-2023), it's 5 hours. Check [this page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york) to learn more about it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Jon is close, but due to character restrictions I can't edit his answer. This is the same code but with "EDT" changed to "EST" for Eastern Standard Time.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
int edtOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getOffset(currentTime);
int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").getOffset(currentTime);
int hourDifference = (gmtOffset - edtOffset) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
String diff = hourDifference + " hours";
```

But this solution makes a major assumption that TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() has within it's string array both "EST" and "GMT". If that method doesn't contain those timezone strings it will come back as 0 offset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code two calculate the time difference between two different timezones.
like current timezone(GMT+05:00) and foreign timezone(GMT+05:30).

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
                Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(foreigntimezone)), today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(currenttimezone)));
                holder.textViewTimeDifference.setText(timeDifference.toString());
            } else {
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diffMilliSeconds = TimeZone.getTimeZone(gmtReplaceUTC).getOffset(now) - TimeZone.getTimeZone(currentTimeZone).getOffset(now);
                if (diffMilliSeconds > 0) {
                    String timeDifference = formatTime(diffMilliSeconds);
                    holder.textViewTimeDifference.setText(timeDifference);
                } else {
                    String timeDifference = formatTime(-diffMilliSeconds);
                    holder.textViewTimeDifference.setText("-" + timeDifference);
                }
            }
}
```

Result:
for above 26 API level (PT+30M) and for below (30:00)