# Getting hours between 2 timezones

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I'd like to get the number of hours between 2 different time-zones. I'm currently using Joda time but it looks like it's taking daylight savings into account because it's off by an hour. The only correct one seems to be my current timezone where it returns 0 hours but if I use London for instance which for me is 5 hr difference it returns 4.

Current code:

```
DateTime endTime = new DateTime(date);
DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime);
int hours = period.getHours();
```

Comment: what about  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760031/android-how-to-get-time-difference-between-two-time-zones-in-android">Java: Difference between timezones in hours</a>

Comment: Last link seemed to work, thanks ginger!