# Java: getTimeZone without returning a default value

Tags: java, timezone

I have the following instruction:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Toyo");
```

Obviously, it should return null, but it will return the default timeZone, which is not the desired behaviour for my case. From Java Doc:

> Returns the specified `TimeZone`, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood.

Is there a way to get corresponding TimeZone and null value if the String does not indicate a valid TimeZone?

I don't find a good solution to get all TimeZones and iterate over them.

Comment: Instead of iterating over all available tzids you might consider to check the result only if it is GMT. If so then check if your input is "GMT" or "UTC" or "UT" or "GMT0" or similar. If yes then ok else return null.

Answer (score 6):

## `java.time.ZoneId`

The old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Instead of `java.util.TimeZone`, you should be using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). For parsing a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), call [`ZoneId.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-).

```
ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Casablanca" )
```

### Trap for `ZoneRulesException`

If the name you pass in unrecognized, the method throws a [`ZoneRulesException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesException.html).

So, to catch a misspelling of [`Asia/Tokyo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Tokyo) as `Asia/Toyo`, trap for the [`ZoneRulesException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesException.html).

```
ZoneId z;
try {
    z = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Toyo" );  // Misspell "Asia/Tokyo" as "Asia/Toyo".
} catch ( ZoneRulesException e ) {
    System.out.println ( "Oops! Failed to recognize your time zone name. ZoneRulesException message: " + e.getMessage () );
    return;
}
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now ( z );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/WSvaW6).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating you could also simply use:

```
boolean exists = Arrays.asList(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()).contains("Asia/Toyo");
```

or:

```
boolean exists = Arrays.stream(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()).anyMatch("Asia/Toyo"::equals);
```

If you need to do that often, putting the available IDs in a HashSet would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your need [TimeZone validation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092865/timezone-validation-in-java)

```
String[] validIDs = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
for (String str : validIDs) {
      if (str != null && str.equals("yourString")) {
        System.out.println("Valid ID");
      }
}
```

Comment: I know you just copied the answer, but do you really think `getAvailableIDs()` will return a null value?

Comment: getAvailableIDs() won't return a null value, but it will allow you to know if the timezone is a valid one (That was part of his question)

Comment: I was referring to the `str != null` check.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry; well indeed doesn't seems that useful to check for null in this line :D

Answer (score 0):

Just check the returned [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

```
public static TimeZone getTimeZone(String timeZoneID) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID);
    if (timeZone.getID().equals(timeZoneID))
        return timeZone;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown time zone: " + timeZoneID);
}
```

In Java 8, use the new [`ZoneId.of(String zoneId)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-), which will fail for unknown time zones, and [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId zoneId)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.time.ZoneId-) if you need the old `TimeZone`:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Toyo");
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId);
```

Comment: The [documentation for TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) explicitly points out that the returned object may have an ID string different from what you request, such as `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8")`.

Comment: @VGR True, but the other answers, which search the available IDs, will fail for the same reason. A non-standard ID will be changed, and will not be in the list. As such, this is a better, yet still imperfect, solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate over TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(). You can use.

```
boolean validateTimeZone(String timeZoneStr) {
    return TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneStr).getID().matches(timeZoneStr);
}
```

Comment: This fails for time zone IDs with a plus (`+`)  in them such as `Etc/GMT+2` since `matches()` interprets its argument as a regular expression, and the plus has a special meaning in regex.