# Timezone Abbreviations in Java

Tags: java

I have a collection of Java [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) objects, loaded from an old database which did not store timezone info.

I know that all the dates (which include hours, minutes and seconds) are for the U.S. Eastern time zone.

I want to derive the correct timezone abbreviation ("EST" or "EDT") for each date.

Here is my attempt (using Java 11). It is unwieldy, to say the least.

I looked into the following classes:

```
java.util.TimeZone
java.time.ZoneId
java.time.zone.ZoneRules
```

Here is my method - it uses two statements purely to give me a fighting chance of still understanding what I wrote, a week from now.

***EDIT - based on @VGR's comment below, I have updated the example. Now it expects a timezone display name - for example `"America/New_York"`:***

```
public String getTimezoneAbbrev(Date date, String tzName) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzName);
    boolean isDaylightSavings = tz.toZoneId().getRules().isDaylightSavings(date.toInstant());
    return tz.getDisplayName(isDaylightSavings, TimeZone.SHORT);
}
```

It works (I have test cases), but **is there a less verbose way?**

(I did not find any code examples which use `Date` as their starting point).

Comment: The first line could be `boolean isDaylightSavings = TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(date);`

Comment: I’m confused by your use of `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")` on one line and `TimeZone.getDefault()` on the next.  I would have thought you’d want to use the same timezone everywhere.  Maybe even store it in a static final field?

Comment: @VGR - Yes that is confusing (i.e. bad and wrong).  I have fixed my example - thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()),TimeZone.SHORT));
    }
}
```

Comment: Arvind (and @Dawood also): Ironically, I was using `ZoneRules.isDaylightSavings()` out of a wish to use the modern `java.time.zone` package.  But `TimeZone.inDaylightTime()` is what I need, thanks. I completely missed it. Available since Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Arvind's answer because he pointed out `TimeZone.inDaylightTime()` - but for the record, here is the updated version of the method in my question.

It is more concise now:

```
// tzName is a timezone display name, such as "America/New_York"

public static String getTimezoneAbbrev(Date date, String tzName) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzName);
    return tz.getDisplayName(tz.inDaylightTime(date), TimeZone.SHORT);        
}
```

### Warning

I also found answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373442/java-gettimezone-without-returning-a-default-value) helpful - because if you type a non-existent timezone display name (or ID) when using TimeZone.getTimeZone(), Java will return "the specified TimeZone, ***or the GMT zone*** if the given ID cannot be understood" (emphasis mine). [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)).

Typing...

`America/New-York`

...instead of...

`America/New_York`

...is enough to cause problems.

### Therefore...

We should use [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) instead. This will throw an error for an invalid/unknown ID.