# TimeZone doesn't match up right

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I'm using Java's default `TimeZone` and `Calendar` classes to try and get the time of different areas, however when I try to use it, it doesn't take into account any +0x:00. For example when I enter "Europe/England" it returns me 1:30, when it's actually 2:30 since right now England is using GMT+1, not GMT.

```java
String timeZone = raw.split(" ")[1];
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone tz;

try {
    tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
} catch (Exception e) {
    event.getChannel().sendMessage("Couldn't find time-zone for: " + timeZone +
        ".\n*Usage: !time <continent/city>*\n*You can find TZ names here: " +
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List*").queue();
    return;
}

long hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
String minutes = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
if (minutes.length() == 1)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
User author = event.getAuthor();
event.getChannel().sendMessage(author.getAsMention() + " The current time is: **" + hours + ":" + minutes + "** [" + tz.getDisplayName() + "]").queue();
```

Comment: Can you put value of raw ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: getTimeZone without returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373442/java-gettimezone-without-returning-a-default-value)

Comment: There is no zone called `Europe/England`, you just get the GMT zone back right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you switch to modern [date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) instead of using the outdated date/time API.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(zdt.getHour());
        System.out.println(zdt.getMinute());

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLiteral("Hour: ")
                .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                .appendLiteral(", Minute: ")
                .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR)
                .toFormatter();
        System.out.println(formatter.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-11T14:54:34.081332+01:00[Europe/London]
14
54
Hour: 14, Minute: 54
```

Comment: The time is now correct however now I can't input things like 'England' anymore.

Comment: @AlexHammond `Europe/England` is not a valid timezone - I'm surprised the old APIs accept it.  As your exception-catching comment says, "Usage: !time <continent/ **city** >", and you'll notice it doesn't appear in the list linked there either.  "England" isn't a city; "Europe/London" is the correct timezone name for the UK, and the one you should be using.

Comment: Thanks,  Andrzej Doyle. @AlexHammond - You can print [java.util.TimeZone#getAvailableIDs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29) to verify that there is no timezone such as `Europe/England`.

Comment: @AlexHammond This is why you should not use the old API. It silently rejects your invalid timezone name and defaults to GMT - see the javadoc entry [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) - "_the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood._"

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).