# How to change timezone of date android kotlin [HH:mm]

Tags: android, kotlin, simpledateformat, android-calendar, timezone-offset

As input, I get a string like HH:mm, which is UTC. But I need to convert the time to +3 hours (i.e. UTC +3).

For example, it was 12:30 - it became 15:30.

I tried this code, but its not working :(

```
fun String.formatDateTime(): String {
    val sourceFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    sourceFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    val parsed = sourceFormat.parse(this)

    val tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+3")
    val destFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    destFormat.timeZone = tz

    return parsed?.let { destFormat.format(it) }.toString()
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does the date matter resp. does DST matter or could you simply add three hours?

Comment: @deHaar I updated the question with the code that didn't work for me

Comment: hours += 3; if( hours >23){ hours-=24;} and format it

Comment: *but its not working* -- in which way not working? Which result are you observing instead, exactly?

Comment: Time zones tend to change their offset from UTC from time to time, not only because of summer time (DST). So given a time of day such as 12:30 and a time zone ID such as Asia/Kuwait, you will also need a date so that you can apply the correct offset for that date.

Comment: You will want to check what you get from `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+3")`. Does this answer your question? [Java: getTimeZone without returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373442/java-gettimezone-without-returning-a-default-value). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325706/timezone-doesnt-match-up-right) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072438/error-when-i-try-to-change-my-time-date-to-utc-1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.time` for this and if you just want to add a specific amount of hours, you can use `LocalTime.parse(String)`, `LocalTime.plusHours(Long)` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")`. Here's a small example:

```
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun String.formatDateTime(hoursToAdd: Long): String {
    val utcTime = LocalTime.parse(this)
    val targetOffsetTime = utcTime.plusHours(hoursToAdd)
    return targetOffsetTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))
}

fun main() {
    println("12:30".formatDateTime(3))
}
```

Output is simply `15:30`.

Try it with `"22:30"` and you'll get `"01:30"` as output.

Please note that daylight saving time may cause problems if you are not supposed to just add three hours but consider a real time zone whose offset from UTC may change.

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

### Solution using java.time API

Parse the given time string using [`LocalTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and then convert it into a UTC `OffsetTime` by using [`LocalTime#atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-). The final step is to convert this UTC `OffsetTime` into an `OffsetTime` at the offset of `+03:00` which you can do by using [`OffsetTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-).

Note that you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your time string as it is already in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is the default format that is used by `java.time` types.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sampleTime = "12:30";
        OffsetTime offsetTime = LocalTime.parse(sampleTime)
                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+03:00"));
        System.out.println(offsetTime);

        // Getting LocalTine from OffsetTime
        LocalTime result = offsetTime.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
15:30+03:00
15:30
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/FYsCaA)

Alternatively:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sampleTime = "12:30";
        OffsetTime offsetTime = OffsetTime.of(LocalTime.parse(sampleTime), ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+03:00"));
        System.out.println(offsetTime);

        // Getting LocalTine from OffsetTime
        LocalTime result = offsetTime.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Xma41a)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from [Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Nice addition to simply adding 3 hours! This is better than my answer when it comes to considering daylight saving time and/or zones.

Comment: @deHaar Thanks for your kind words. As long as an answer meets OP's requirement, it deserves credit and therefore your answer does deserve the credit. I hurriedly read your answer and thought to write this answer using the `OffsetTime`. I was so busy that I completed my answer in three attempts. I just returned to this page again.

Answer (score 2):

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun getDayOfWeekOfMonthDateFormat(timeZone: String? = "GMT"): SimpleDateFormat {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM EEEE dd")
    timeZone?.let {
        format.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(it)
    }
    return format
}
```

This is function for returning "GMT" as default and if you wanna change,  add "GMT+5:30"

NB: change the format with your requirement