# How to get correct getTimeZone by passing string value with offset in java

Tags: java, spring, timezone, java.util.date

I have a use case where I get `timeZoneId` in `UTC` `+/-` format as `String`. Based on that I need to set correct `timeZone` in Java. Does anyone know the correct way of doing it?

For example:

```
String timeZoneId = "UTC+01:00";
TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId); <- Ideally it should set timezone of CET.
```

But it does not. It set default timeZone GMT.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have a time zone ID, you have the UTC offset. A time zone ID is e.g. "Europe/Berlin". There is no way to set the correct time zone only with the offset.

Comment: You will get about 30 different `ZoneId`s having an offset of `+01:00` (at the moment). How do you want to choose the correct one? Considering daylight saving time would alter the amount depending on the day of year you run a choosing code.

Comment: That is not completely right. A time zone ID is not only "Europe/Berlin" but also e.g. "GMT+1" or "GMT+01:00". UTC however is not supported by TimeZone as an ID. So if you can get your timeZoneId in GMT format instead of UTC then you would be able to create a TimeZone instance from it.

Comment: Yes, I know GMT is taken by TimeZone instance. Unfortunately I am getting it only in UTC. Can we some how convert UTC to GMT? @StrongPoint

Comment: Don’t use `TimeZone` nor `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, not worth struggling with. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and its `ZoneId` class for time zones.

Comment: CET is the common name for a great many European and African time zones using offset +01:00 in winter. Most of them, not all, use offset +02:00 in summer. Which of those zones do you want? Specify as for example Europe/Stockholm or Africa/Ceuta.

Comment: Related: [Java: getTimeZone without returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373442/java-gettimezone-without-returning-a-default-value)

Comment: I believe that all that you need is the `ZoneId` you get from `ZoneId.of(timeZoneId)`. It’s exactly `UTC+01:00`, so not CET, but it sounds like that’s OK for your purpose? If you thought that you needed an old-fashioned `TimeZone` object for a `Calendar`, a `DateFormat` or another old class, — **don’t**. Stay away from those old and troublesome classes and instead use `ZonedDateTime` with your `ZoneId`. In case you can’t avoid calling some legacy method that requires a `TimeZone`, you may use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of(timeZoneId).normalized())` to translate to a `TimeZone` of `GMT+01:00`

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You cannot reliably determine a time zone from an offset. Your question is illogical.

## Details

> `timeZoneId = "UTC+01:00`

No, that is not a time zone. That is merely an offset.

- An **offset** is a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC/GMT. Simply a number, nothing more.
- A **time zone** is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians. A [time zone has a name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Asia/Tokyo` or `Africa/Tunis`.

> Based on that I need to set correct timeZone in Java.

Not possible. Many time zones may share the same offset.

Take your example of +01:00. Many time zones may share that offset. These include Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Algiers, Africa/Ndjamena, Africa/Lagos, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Malta, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Paris, and many more.

So an offset does not map to a time zone one-to-one.

Furthermore, the offset used by a time zone varies over time. This happens for various reasons. An invading army may dictate a certain time zone in its occupied territory. A politician may change the time zone of their jurisdiction to annoy or appease a neighboring country. Or some loopy politicians may decide to require their citizens go to bed an hour earlier or open their shops an hour later, in a practice known as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

The offset changing in a locality over time means that you cannot determine the offset in effect without specifying a date and time along with the name of a time zone.

> Ideally it should set timezone of CET

No, `CET` is not a time zone. Such 2-4 letter abbreviations are pseudo zones that hint at a time zone, and indicate whether Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect or not. But these pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique. Avoid them.  Use real time zones with names of `Continent/Region`.

> Does anyone know how to achieve this?

If you mean “How to achieve determining a time zone from a given offset?”, you cannot. That is not possible as discussed above.

> Can we some how convert UTC to GMT

[UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [GMT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) are the same thing when speaking practically, in common business contexts. The difference is less than a second.

---

All of this has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.